# 'have our destiny worked out' or 'work out our destiny'

Tags: passive-voice

have something done

We've been taught two usages of the structure.

- A. the things that you have others do for you.
  eg: *I just went out to have my hair cut*.
- B. something bad happened to you
  eg: *I just had my wallet stolen.*

but I cannot figure out which usage this sentence belongs to:

- We figured that in twenty years each of us ought to have our destiny worked out and our fortunes made, whatever they were going to be.

My questions would be:

1. what does the 'have our destiny worked out' really mean?
2. why don't we just say 'work out our destiny'?

Comment: 'Have something worked/figured out' is neither sense A nor sense B, but means 'have thought deeply about possibilities, with regard to a problem, a situation, or even one's future, and be [as] certain [as one thinks appropriate] that one has the definitive answer.' Try finding that in a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it's just a post-verbal participle: _We have the fish fried_, not the perfect _have fried the fish_.

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally get it.

This is the explanation from "Collins COBUILD overhaul":

"
VERB [no passive] If you have something such as a part of your body in a particular position or state, it is in that position or state.

Mary had her eyes closed.

They had the curtains open.

He had his shirt buttoned.

As I was working, I had the radio on.

He had his hand on Maria's shoulder.
"

So I suppose the question should just mean "We figured that in twenty years each of us ought to **work out our destiny and make our fortunes**, whatever the future were going to be like.

Comment: Good find Steven! It talks about being at the completed state.